# MATLAB: force doc command to open a specified reference HTML page

Tags: matlab

Say I've written a class in a package, called `mypackage.myclass`. I've written my own HTML documentation for the package and the class, and have included this within the MATLAB help browser as described in [the MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f3-40511.html).

I can display this HTML documentation by using the help browser to navigate directly to it, but typing `doc mypackage.myclass` does not display it; instead it displays some HTML documentation that is auto-generated by `helpwin` (which is a nice feature, but not what I want - the auto-generated documentation is too techy for my users).

How can I force `doc` to display my documentation, rather than the auto-generated documentation?

Equivalently:

When you run `doc docTopic`, inside the doc command the Java class `com.mathworks.mlservices.MLHelpServices.showReferencePage(docTopic)` gets called. If a reference page for `docTopic` exists, it displays it and returns a success value. If a reference page doesn't exist, it returns a failure value, which then causes `helpwin(docTopic)` to get called. Somewhere there must be some catalog that connects values of `docTopic` with individual reference HTML files. How can I fiddle with that catalog - or can I create one for my package?

MathWorkers and @Yair, please give me enough undocumented rope to hang myself with :)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a mistake somewhere? The [xUnit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846-matlab-xunit-test-framework) package seems to be doing fine in terms of documentation.

Comment: @Jonas Yes - when I run `doc runtests` or `doc TestComponent`, I get the HTML documentation that is auto-generated for those classes by `helpwin`. Although xUnit includes some great tutorial documentation (I don't have a problem doing that), it doesn't include its own separate HTML documentation for the classes/functions themselves.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood your question before. I guess then the question becomes: will it be easier to educate people to use `doc mypackage` to access the hyperlinked help?

Comment: Perhaps somewhere inside `[matlab_root]\toolbox\matlab\helptools`? I haven't exhaustively searched there, but it might exist.

Comment: Plot thickens ... but it was fun so far. I've hit rock bottom when it starts using the Apache Lucene engine (`com.mathworks.mlwidgets.help.search.lucene.LuceneDocSearchEngine`). My guess is that some (seemingly obfuscated) textfile searcing is going on to find the exact URL for the help file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible and not intended by MathWorks. I don't know of an undocumented way of doing this either. As far as I remember the keywords for `doc` are hard-coded somewhere.

Depending on your setup you can try the following: Prepare your own `doc` command that uses `web(..., '-helpbrowser')` to display HTML pages in MATLAB's help browser:

```
function doc(topic)

    my_topics = {
        'foo', 'foo.html'
        'bar', 'bar/help/intro.html'
    };

    for i = 1 : size(my_topics, 1)
        if strcmpi(topic, my_topics{i, 1})      
            web(my_topics{i, 2}, '-helpbrowser');
            return;
        end
    end

    % Fall back to MATLAB's doc. Note that our doc shadows MATLAB's doc.
    docs = which('doc', '-all');
    old_dir = cd();
    c = onCleanup(@() cd(old_dir));
    cd(fileparts(docs{2}));
    doc(topic); 
end
```

If you put that function in a file `doc.m` and put the corresponding directory at the beginning of the MATLAB path (see `help addpath`) then it will be called instead of the built-in `doc`.

Of course you could use some other place to store your custom doc mapping (a file, for instance) or use some kind of dynamic lookup scheme.

**UPDATE:** As of MATLAB R2012b, the `'-helpbrowser'` option of `web` is undocumented. This is probably related to the GUI changes in that MATLAB version, which also include the help browser. `web(..., '-helpbrowser')` still works as intended, but that may change in future versions of MATLAB. As far as I know, there is no documented way of opening *any* HTML page in the help browser in R2012b.

Comment: It would make me feel a bit dirty to shadow the doc command like that, but as a hack it looks like it might work. Of course, it's going to get more complicated if I have multiple packages like this and they each need their own doc command. I'm going to accept, though, as it's the closest to a solution that I have so far after a long time. Thanks.

Comment: @SamRoberts: Glad you like it. It is a hack, no doubt, and using it for several independent projects will lead to trouble. We faced the same problem and decided to ship our own ``doc`` command with another name instead of shadowing ``doc``. The downside is that users have to remember what command to use.