# Use external browser to view matlab help pages

Tags: matlab, browser, configuration

On a Linux machine I want `Matlab 2015a` to use Firefox instead of the (buggy) internal browser as help browser when running `doc COMMAND` or pressing `F1`.

How can I configure this in a `startup.m` file?

I can not see the suggested browser option in 2015a preferences:

[image: screenshot of MATLAB Help Prefs]

Comment: I suggest you indicate Matlab version and operating system, as the answer may depend on that.

Comment: @LuisMendo thank you for your suggestion. Question updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that unfortunately this is not possible anymore. Actually it used to be possible by shadowing the `doc` function (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410120/matlab-force-doc-command-to-open-a-specified-reference-html-page)), but I've just tried (R2015a, Ubuntu) and though the `doc` function is indeed shadowed:

```
>> which('doc', '-all')
/home/.../doc.m
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/toolbox/matlab/helptools/doc.m     % Shadowed
```

any call to `doc` still opens the builtin `doc`. The Matlab developpers have probably locked this possibility in the latest releases.

There is anyway a setting that may interest you: in the preferences you can choose to display the web-based documentation instead of the local one. So, if your local doc is broken, it may worth a try !

[image]

Best,

Comment: I could not see this option in Matlab 2015a for Linux. How can I enable it?

Comment: @JonasStein: I'm using Matlab R2015a on Ubuntu, academic licence, and I definitively have the option. The image is a direct screenshot of my parameters window. I've just double checked at the moment. If you don't have it, it may be a bug or a licence-specific option (strange) ... you should contact the Mathworks.

Comment: Total guess, but perhaps he never installed the docs locally.  If that's the case maybe they detect that and don't give him an option to use the local documentation since there is none?

Answer (score 2):

At first pass, this looks like an option only for the linux version of Matlab.  See the bottom of this page: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/web-browsers-and-matlab.html

Will keep an eye out...

Comment: The option is used for `web 'stackoverflow.com' ` but it is ignored for `doc plot`